# Change view within document folder

Tags: sharepoint-online

Can you change the view (e.g. set different columns with different names) within a specific folder created in a document library? As of now, I'm experiencing that every folder created in a document library uses the same view.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is available OOTB (Out Of The Box), but as many things well hidden.

You have to turn on management of Content Types:

1. In Ribbon click Library Settings
2. Click Advanced settings
3. Allow management of content type
4. OK

Now when you create/modify a view you have the option to make the view the default view (and the top) AND down in the group "Folders" a new section is enabled "Show this view" with the options:

- In all folders
- In the top-level folder
- In folders of content type [Drop down]

This allows you to select a different default view for the top-level folder and all other folders. And if you need a folder to have a special view, then you can:

1. Create a new content type inheriting from folder
2. Assign that content type to the list
3. Change the folder to have that content type
4. Create the view to set as default for folders of this content type

Note that you need to both make the view default and select it to be shown for this level/content type for it to be shown by default.

Comment: I followed until the "create a new content type inheriting..." part near the bottom. Do I go to my documents settings "add from existing site content types"?

Comment: Yes, that's the "Assign that content type to the list" part

Comment: My In folders of content type drop down menu line is grayed out.